# Running Python scripts as job (RHEL 6)

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have setup a jenkins(1.6) job which will build periodically.
The job is a python script that needs to be executed.

The Global Path of the setup is `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` ,
the build is using:

```
EXPORT PATH=%PATH:%PYTHON_PATH%
python home/scripttest/test.py
```

After this the following errors in the console output appear:

> [pytest] $ python /tmp/hudson9090694322529044967.py
>   [pytest] $ cmd /c call /tmp/hudson868114309999030575.bat
>   FATAL: command execution failed
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/home/marc/workspace/pytest"): error=2, No such file or directory

**Note I don't want to use a subversion.

Comment: You're using Windows-style variable references, and `cmd`, yet you appear to be running on Linux. Make sure your build is running on the right kind of machine. The "Execute shell" step will only run on non-Windows systems,  and "Run Windows Batch file" only on Windows. Otherwise, your builds will fail.

Comment: do not add SOLVED to the title of your question, if any of the answers is the solution then mark it as the correct one, if instead you have found the solution then create an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: @eyllanesc Done ,marked as correct one

Comment: @jamesorc no, you have not done it, one thing is the upvote and another is to mark it as correct, check the [tour] for more information.

Comment: upvoted & marked as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be running the build on Linux, but seem to have included a "Run Windows Batch file" step in your build, as shown by the attempt to run `cmd /c call <temporary-file>.bat`.

As the Windows command prompt doesn't exist on Linux, you get the error:

> Cannot run program "cmd"

Comment: what needs to done in order to fix this?
I have tried using "run a shell command" too
adding in build step 
#!usr/bin/sh
python <path to file>

this too doesn't works

Comment: If you're running on Linux, remove the "Run Windows Batch file" step. If you're seeing a different error now, you should update your question with it.